# Dynamically adding a button in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Hello im trying to add a button but i keep getting this error: 
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams)' on a null object reference`

this is my code, it works well in regular activity, its not working as a fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fav, container, false);

    lSecond = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.lSecond);
    lThird = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.lThird);
    return v;
}
 public void bCreate(String i)
{
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams btnParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(matchParent, wrapContent);
    Button btnNew = new Button(this.getActivity());
    btnNew.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
    btnNew.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    btnNew.setText(i);
    scale =  getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int top = (int) (5 * scale + 0.5f);
    int bot = (int) (5 * scale + 0.5f);
    if (Second < Third)
    {
        int left = (int) (10 * scale + 0.5f);
        int right = (int) (5 * scale + 0.5f);
        btnParams.leftMargin = left;
        btnParams.rightMargin = right;
        btnParams.topMargin = top;
        btnParams.bottomMargin = bot;
        lSecond.addView(btnNew, btnParams);
        Second++;
        btnNew.setOnClickListener(listen);
    }
```

bCreate is getting called in onCreate, and String i - is a String from database

Comment: Maybe  this will help https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4eF5.png Decouple your *model* from your *view*. This looks like you're generating a bunch of strings in `onCreate` (your model). And you should create a bunch of `Button`s in `onViewCreated` according to the array of strings you created earlier (the view). The view reflects the model. Don't do both at the same time. View is not even available as early as `onCreate` hence the NPE.

Comment: Where is `bCreate()` being called from?

Comment: @SammyT its getting called in onCreate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bCreate()` is being called too early. You're trying to access `lSecond` before it has a value. Call `bCreate()` in `onCreateView()` just before the return.

Comment: Yep, that is the answer, thank you. I need to pay more attention at fragment`s lifecycle/